# Is it possible to express a language with infinite number of strings using a finite regular expression?

Tags: regex, regular-language, finite-automata

I am trying to understand how to generate a regular expression for some grammars that I suppose are kind of "Infinite". I have the following a `Σ = {0,1}` I thought of the following three cases and here are the guesses that I gave.

1. The set of all strings with `0` and ending in `11`. The regular expression that I have is the following: `0+ [1*] [0*] 1+ 1`. However, I know that this expression won't cover all the set of the existing strings in that set.
2. The set of all strings containing at least two consecutive `1`s. The regular expression that I have is the following: `1 1+ [0+] [1+] 1`. Same issue as the first point.
3. The set of all strings beginning with `0`s and not having two consecutive `1`s. The regular expression that I have is the following: `0+ 1 0+ 1 [0+]`. Same issue as the first and second point.

My question is the following: Is there a possibility to express these languages that have infinite number of strings with a finite regular expression. If yes, how exactly?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ANY regular language can be recognized by a finite automaton, and a regular language MAY express an infinite number of matching strings. Addressing your three examples:

1. `0 (0|1)* 1 1`
2. `(0|1)* 1 1 (0|1)*`
3. `0+ (1 0+)+ 1?`

Comment: A minor point (irrelevant to the discussion): `(0|1)` can be expressed ever so slightly more concise, and far more "regex engine friendly", as `[01]`.